# How to check whether one node in API response has same value under all object using postman tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, postman, functional-testing

Suppose a API request fetches a users id, email address and their designated role. Sample API Request below:

```
GET: /v1/users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: bearer {access_token}
```

For the above request, the following is the response:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "random@random.com",
            "full_name": "AlbusDumbledore",
            "role": "OWNER"
        },
        {
            "id": 40,
            "email": "random1@random1.com",
            "role": "OWNER"
        }
],
    "last": false,
    "total_elements": 2,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "sort": null,
    "first": true,
    "number_of_elements": 2,
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0
}
```

Now, what will be the test in postman to make sure that all the returned values under role node is equal to OWNER?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add something like a loop to check for it?

```
pm.test("Check role equals OWNER", () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json()
    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.content.length; i++) { 
        pm.expect(jsonData.content[i].role).to.equal('OWNER')
    }
})
```

This should work to check the value of each `role` property, if the schema response you posted is correct.

I changed one of the values and ran the test again to show you it working - This will show the failure in Postman if the property is not equal to 'OWNER'.

[image]